# How to set none working days in MS Project server 2013 project web app page

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013, project-server

I have setup MS Project 2013 server, and created project web apps

I created enterprise projects

How can I set none working days in MS Project Enterprise web app site or the

enterprise project of web app site in MS Project server 2013

Comment: ? do  you mean "non-working days"?  (days on which work is not to be performed?)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an enterprise calendar in:

- Settings
- PWA Settings
- Enterprise Data
- Enterprise Calendars
- New Calendar

From [Project Server 2013 Administrator's Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217892.aspx) (page 50)

> Enterprise calendars capture the predefined working hours, holidays,
> and other schedule details within an organization. They are used to
> standardize the working time for all of an organization’s projects. In
> Project Web App, you can view a list of existing calendars, select a
> calendar to edit, or begin the process of creating a new calendar.
> However, to create or modify a calendar, you must have Project
> Professional 2013 installed on the computer that you are using to
> access Project Web App.
>
> A best practice is to modify the Standard
> calendar as the main calendar for your organization. The Standard
> calendar is the default base calendar in Project Server. By modifying
> the Standard calendar to include your organizations holidays and
> hours, you save having to select a different calendar each time you
> create a project or resource.

Comment: can we select different calendars for different projects

Comment: Yes you can. And you can select for resources and tasks too

Comment: How can I select for a project different calendar in project server 2013 web app

Comment: From project professional connected to project server

Comment: I have already created 3 enterprise calendars, my question is how can I select different calendars for different projects which I created

Comment: Open the  project from project professional and change the Enterprise calendar.  You could modify too in project templates to use in new projects. Is it clear? I mean enterprise calendar from project pro connected to project server.